# Why include when you can require in PHP?

Tags: php

What is the point of attempting to `include` or `include_once` a library in PHP if you often have to use `require` or `require_once` instead (as they're usually critically important)?

Comment: I've always wondered.

Comment: Hopefully, my edit just made the question clearer. It's sad seeing so many people miss the point.

Comment: @BoltClock yeah i guess; i'm more or less asking: "if you want to use the functionality of a library, what is the point of choosing to include over require (or vis versa)?" I get that include won't stop the rest of the code from processing, but if you want to use the functionality, and the library fails to load, the program will be faulty anyway...so why even bother.

Comment: Exactly. No idea why some of these answers are getting so many ups.

Comment: @BoltClock & @cfarm54. We get it. We understand. There simply isn't any good reason to use `include`/`include_once` over `require`/`require_once`. And so people are simply stating the differences and recommending one over the other. As @cfarm54 stated, if a needed file fails to load, the system may unstable and unpredictable anyway and the safest, sanest thing to do is to halt execution. From that point a human must debug the problem and deploy a fix.

Comment: @cfarm54: you have answered your own question in your comment. If you want to use libs then require has benefits over include.

Comment: @Harry That's still not the question.  It's *why **ever** use include?* Given that you can keep your code from calling a bad *require* anyway...

Comment: @Renesis thanks. That's exactly what I'm after. I'm asking about the corner cases.

Comment: @cfarm54 Not going to post this as an answer, but a case where I would use include almost exclusively is when I'm using PHP as an alternative for SSI. If I have a header and a footer that's used across every page and something happens that causes the path to break, I don't want my site to break just because I'm missing a banner. The same goes for any trivial scripts (like including a div on every page that displays the date, time, and a breadcrumb list). I would use require for libraries, though, or any database backend stuff. Y'know, non-trivial stuff.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The difference between `include`/`include_once` and `require`/`require_once` is that when a file is not found, the former triggers a warning whereas the latter triggers an error. Opinions may vary but IMO, if a needed file is not present or readable for some reason, this represents a very broken situation and I would rather see an error and halt execution, than have a warning and proceed execution in a clearly broken context. So I believe it to be best practice to use `require`/`require_once` exclusively and avoid `include`/`include_once` altogether.

Comment: From the documentation: "require() is identical to include() except upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error". I guess the difference is how severe you want the error to be reported. If your code can squeeze by without the included file, it shouldn't be a fatal error.

Comment: This has been my gut intuition as well, but just looking for any corner cases of why I should use `include` / `include_once`.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this being best practice?  It's a good answer, if it's true.

Comment: @Renesis: I chose my words carefully. I said "Opinions may vary", "IMO", and "**I believe** it to be best practice". So no, I don't have a reference. This is my opinion. FWIW my opinion is based on 13 years of PHP development experience and a Zend PHP developer certification.

Comment: You can not free any allocated resources, if you just kill the execution completely. If you have (for example) uncommitted transactions the data get lost.

Comment: @KingCrunch: I believe not committing the transaction would be the desirable behavior in case of a failure. Don't you?

Comment: I like clean "rollbacks" more, as well as closing files and such.

Comment: @KingCrunch: Apache/PHP will close any lingering socket connections or file handles when the script dies. I like "clean" rollbacks too but if my code can't even load needed files that are expected to exist and be readable, all bets are off and I don't trust what unpredictable things might happen in a rollback procedure either.

Comment: I believe the OP knows this difference. A good answer would just point out the situation where "include" is  preferred, if any.

Answer (score 45):

Sometimes you are including files from libraries that you do not control or your code is being run on different environments.

It is possible that some of these aren't actually required for your script but are helper files or extras.

For instance, if your PHP is generating HTML, you might use an include to add a banner. But you wouldn't want your file to halt if for some reason that banner file was missing. You'd want to gracefully fail instead.

Answer (score 7):

**include** - this attempts to load a file but does not halt execution if it fails

**include_once** - does the same as 'include' but runs an additional check to make sure the file hasn't already been included in the current script

**require** - this attempts to load a file and throws a fatal error on failure

**require_once** - same as 'require' but runs an additional check to make sure it's loaded only once

If you don't need to use include_once or require_once try to avoid them since the extra check adds a little overhead.

EDIT: I should add that they key difference is that require fails at the *compiler* level, while include throws an error at run-time.

Comment: As I said on [slowkvant's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026642/x/6026663#6026663), while this is true, it's not what the OP was asking. The OP was asking *why* you would want to use `include` instead of `require`; if you're including a file and there's an error, why not treat the error like it should be: as an error.

Comment: Similar to my response to @Asaph, not all loading errors are fatal. There are situations where the failure can be handled in the code elegantly, while others need to fail at the compiler level.

Comment: Why are these being said in comments and not the answers...?

Comment: What do you mean *compiler* vs. *run-time*? It's very easy to see that code prior to a require actually does get executed.  `include` doesn't throw "an error" at all.  It's fatal error vs. warning.

Comment: @soulkphp: I challenge you to come up with a practical example where not loading a file is a tolerable condition.

Comment: @Asaph As @jopke mentioned, some includes have nothing but visual elements like page fragments or HTML blocks. You could very well be attempting to include a "quote of the day" or a cached HTML snippet which may or may not exist. If that include happens to fail, there's no reason to throw a compiler error as opposed to handling it in-script. Yes, there are better ways to write the above code but there are valid cases where the absence of a file isn't fatal.

Comment: @Renesis I was quoting the documentation for require: "upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error"

Answer (score 3):

Require will **stop** the script if it can't include the file.
Include will just **give an** error message.

Btw.: ***_once** is slow. Shouldn't use it unless you really need to.

Comment: That's true, but the question was asking why you would want to use `include` over `require`, not what they do.

Comment: Yes although that's true, if youre trying to use a function in the library with an `include` statement, then your code won't work properly anyway.

Comment: How does this answer relate to anything?

Comment: @icktoofay: We decide the use of any function by what they do. so the answer is okay here.

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't want the missing files stop your show.  ;)

Comment: If there's an error, wouldn't you want it to stop your script and put the error in the error log so you can investigate and fix it? If it went on after an error, it could wreak havoc.

Comment: It depends.  If you're writing an application, you don't need "include"s most of the time.  However, consider now you're trying to write a framework, there will be parts you don't want them stop just because some files are missing.  e.g. bug tracking, log, etc.

Comment: Why would a framework be any different from any other web app? How could a framework continue to run effectively with missing parts? And anyway if the framework used `include`/`include_once` for missing files it might just fill up the logs with annoying warnings during regular execution. I don't think I like this framework.

Comment: @Asaph Unless you want to write an INFLEXIBLE framework, you shouldn't avoid using include blindly.  Take a look at CodeIgniter's libraries first.  You'll see why they haven't abandoned the "include"s from the PHP language.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, **include** will only [generate a warning](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)...

So, if you have potentially missing files (such as dynamically including templates that may be safe to fail) *and* you are suppressing warnings (or don't mind bloated logs) then **file_exists** & **require** simply becomes **include**.

However, that doesn't seem like a very common use case.  The reason that **include** is still very common ([Occam's Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor)?) is more likely, simply this:

- **include** makes more semantic sense, and is seen in other languages.

Comment: then why not make the functionality of `include` the same as `require` and get rid of `require` altogether?

Comment: @cfarm54 I hope you aren't saying this isn't a valid answer unless I know. There are a million reasons they might have started with "include" (probably the C roots) and a million more not to change it.

Answer (score 2):

All four can take a local file or URL as input. `require()` and `include()` functions are virtually similar in their function except for the way they handle an irretrievable resource. `include()` and `include_once()` gives warning if the resource cannot be retrieved and try to continue execution of the program(if possible) while `require()` and `require_once` functions stops processing the page if they cannot find the resource.

It is best to use `require_once()` to include files which contains code and `include_once()` to include files that do not contains code e.g. HTML, CSS, etc. (This is my approach other's can differ.)

Also read this: http://arin.me/blog/php-require-vs-include-vs-require_once-vs-include_once-performance-test

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php starts with:

> The include() statement includes and
>   evaluates the specified file.
>
> The documentation below also applies
>   to require().

And the documentation at http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php says:

> require() is identical to include()
>   except upon failure it will also
>   produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level
>   error. In other words, it will halt
>   the script whereas include() only
>   emits a warning (E_WARNING) which
>   allows the script to continue.
>
> See the include() documentation for
>   how this works.

I think that's enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Difference just in error handling, when required file doesn't exists: in case of `include` you can easily handle warning, change execution to show normal 'Sorry, error' page, send notification to site's admin.
In case of `require` your script will just stopped, fatal error is more difficult to handle, and you can't show any message to user.